# Providing a factory instead of a Type in WCF ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any way to extend `ServiceHost` so that it accepts a factory?

I would like to use dynamic service proxies for some preprocessing of WCF calls without touching the service implementation.

**EDIT**

Now the `ServiceHost` creation looks like

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
```

and i would like to use something like

```
var factory = new ServiceProxyFactory<MyService>();
var host = new MyServiceHost(typeof(MyService), factory);
```

Comment: NO, that's not possible. There's a mechanism to have a factory for the service hosts - but there's no way to have the service hosts take in a factory to create the actual service instances

Comment: @marc_s I thought the same BUT it is possible... see answers below...

Comment: @yahia: interesting - thanks for the links! I'll have to study those in more detail !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not really possible with .NET...

You can implement a [custom ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx) which allows you to customize the behaviour of the ServiceHost and/or the [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) which allows you inspect/modify any message inbound and outbound... IF you really wnat to implement some sort of "dynamic routing" then there is always the [Routing capability of WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_4.aspx)...

Other options (though no 100% solution):

- [WCF service returning another service (service factory?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437411/wcf-service-returning-another-service-service-factory/1437506#1437506)
- [WCF and factory design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065296/wcf-and-factory-design-pattern/7065454#7065454)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx

**EDIT - I stand corrected:**

It is not really possible to use a usual Factory BUT WCF provides the possibility to plug in an `IInstanceProvider` either at the `Service` or the `Endpoint` level...

For further reference see the following links

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx
- [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service/2455039#2455039)
- http://geekswithblogs.net/13DaysaWeek/archive/2010/12/01/dependency-injection-and-wcf-services.aspx
- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b428fb65-08b4-45c8-97cd-47ee1a1eaf41/composing-wcf-applications.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The interface i was looking for is [IInstanceProvider.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx)

```
public class MyServiceInstanceProvider<TService> : IInstanceProvider where TService : new()
{

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
    {
        return ServiceFactory.Create<TService>();
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return ServiceFactory.Create<TService>();
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class MyEndpointBehavior<TService> : IEndpointBehavior where TService : new()
{

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new MyServiceInstanceProvider<TService>();
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class MyServiceHost<TService> : ServiceHost where TService : new()
{
    public MyServiceHost(params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        :base(typeof(TService), baseAddresses)
    {            
    }

    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<ServiceEndpoint> AddDefaultEndpoints()
    {
        var endpoints = base.AddDefaultEndpoints();

        foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
        {
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior<TService>());
        }

        return endpoints;
    }

    public override void AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        base.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior<TService>());
    }

}
```